# STL for_each not working with map in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, stl, functor

I haven't used the STL much before, but I started to on this huffman compression project. Everything seems to work except the "for_each" function, which wont except a function argument. Since I don't normally use xcode (I usually use eclipse cdt) I'm not sure if the problem is with my code or with xcode.

This is the Huff.h file

```
class Huff {
private:
    typedef pair<char, int> c_pair;
    vector<Node> nodes;
    vector<Code> code;
    string content;
    void copy_to(c_pair c);
public:
    Huff(string);
    ~Huff();

    string compress();
    bool set_content();
    string get_content();
    string get_compress();
};
```

And this is the part of the Huff.cpp file that will not work.

```
//---Compress---

void Huff::copy_to(c_pair c){
    Node n(c.second, c.first, NULL, NULL);
    nodes.push_back(n);
}
string Huff::compress(){
    map<char, int> freq;
    for(int i = 0; i < content.length(); i++)
        freq[content[i]]++;
    for_each(freq.begin(), freq.end(), copy_to); //I've also tried this->copy_to
    return "110";
}
```

Comment: Try this: `for_each(freg.begin(), freq.end(), mem_fun(&Huff::copy_to));` You need to include `<functional>`.

Comment: @mkb: No, that is not an answer. `std::mem_fun` doesn't know about the `this` pointer on which the member function is to be invoked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for_each(freq.begin(), freq.end(), copy_to); //I've also tried this->copy_to
```

`copy_to` is a member function which cannot be passed to `std::for_each`.

What you need is a callable entity which doesn't need implicit `this` : such an entity can be either *functor* or *free function*, and in C++11, *lambda* also.

The lambda solution would be pretty simple if you can use it:

```
for_each(freq.begin(), 
         freq.end(), 
         [this](c_pair & c) { this->copy_to(c); } );
```

Learn about lambda expression here:

- [What is a lambda expression in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11)

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out, you can't use a member function that way with `for_each`.

The C++03 alternative is to use `mem_fun` and `bind1st` to build a function object:

```
std::for_each(freq.begin(), freq.end(), 
              std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&Huff::copy_to), this));
```

Or using [Boost.Bind](http://www.boost.org/libs/bind/):

```
std::for_each(freq.begin(), freq.end(), 
              boost::bind(&Huff::copy_to, this, _1));
```